# xaml path data for arrow

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have trying to draw simple "up" arrow by this code:

```
    <Canvas Width="500" Height="500">
            <Path Height="120" Width="120" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Red" Data="M 60,60 L 60,0 L 50,10 L 60,0 L 70,10"/>         
    </Canvas>
```

And I don't see symmetric arrow on my screen.

I want to understand this "magic".

Comment: Your path data is incorrect for it to be symmetrical for starters. I'd either cheat and just use blend, illustrator, or inkscape to generate the path data. However in this specific instance, being what it is, I would just use an ascii\unicode icon like `&#8593;` `\2191`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have created a Path that is 120x120.  Coordinate 0,0 is the upper-left corner.

M 60, 60  ->  Move to the very center of the Path object x=60,y=60

L 60,0 -> Draw a Line from the last coordinate (60,60) to x=60,y=0 (straight up)

L 50,10 -> Draw a Line from the last coordinate (60,0) to x=50,y=10 (to the left 10 and down 10)

L 60, 0 -> Draw a Line from the last coordinate (50,10) to x=60, y=0 (retrace your line up and to the right by 10 each)

L 70,10 ->  Draw a Line from the last coordinate (60,0) to x=70,y=10 ( to right 10 and down 10)

[image]

The reason that it is not symmetrical is because you are backtracking along the left arm of the arrow.  This adds a join at that point, and essentially adds more to the line there because of your stroke thickness.

You can fix that like this:

```
        <Path Height="120" Width="120"
                    StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Red" Data="M 60,60 L 60,0 L 50,10 M60,0 L70,10"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Good job going the step to explain it! +1